# Прописная или строчная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Никак не могу понять, когда слово *управление* пишется с большой буквы. Например, в предложении

> управление образования администрации ?
> муниципального района

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это официальное название учреждения, значит, первое слово с большой буквы.

Начальник Управления образования администрации ? муниципального района

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже так думала, но не была уверена.